# XDMP Function: String to XML

Tags: xquery, marklogic

Is there any method defined in marklogic function library, by which we can convert (or try to convert) a string (`xs:string` type) to an xml '`document`' type? In my problem, I shall normally get an xml sent through request parameters. now I have to `parse` this xml as a document. So I have to take it as a string and parse it. What is the solution for this case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think [xdmp:unquote](http://docs.marklogic.com/xdmp%3aunquote) is what you are looking for.

Answer (score 1):

In XQuery 3.0 simply use the standard XPath 3.0 function **[`parse-xml()`](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions-30/#func-parse-xml)**.

Answer (score 1):

```
xdmp:eval("<ok/>")
```

or

```
xdmp:value("<ok/>")
```

Both of them can be use for your problem.

Regards